# Volley Request Android - Strings + Images

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-volley

i just wanted to ask a question regarding the Volley library for making HTTP requests to the server in android.

I'm having a certain query that returns for example, the user's info(name,email,address...etc) along with those, the **ImagePath** for the user on the server. I've seen in volley both:

> 1) **String requests** to get the user info.
>
> 2) **Image requests** to get the user's image bitmap by giving it the ImagePath.

My question is:

**Is there a way to do both together at the same time? (i.e retrieving the info along with the BITMAP(not the path) using one volley request?**

NOTE:

I have to do this in a sequential way, meaning that of course to get the bitmap i have to perform first, the query that gets all the info but then i need to get the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

USER REQUEST

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http:url...",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                  imageRequest(imagePath);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                   error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

    int socketTimeout = 60000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

IMAGE REQUEST

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http:url...",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //get user's image
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                   error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

    int socketTimeout = 60000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: in the comment "get user's image", how can i copy it to an external data structure, i've done the previous code so far.